# RxJava - remove item from cached observable

Tags: caching, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using code that looks like following:

```
public Observable<DBContact> getFriends()
{
    if (mFriends == null)
    {
        mFriends = Observable
                .fromIterable(MainApp.getDB().getAll(DBContact.TABLE, new DBContact(), null))
                .compose(RxUtil.cacheAndShare());
    }
    return mFriends;
}
```

With following helper functions:

```
public static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> cacheAndShare()
{
    return new ObservableTransformer<T, T>()
    {
        @Override
        public ObservableSource<T> apply(Observable<T> observable)
        {
            return observable.cache().replay().refCount();
        }
    };
}
```

Now I want to edit the cached data in this observable. I can simple reset the `mFriends` variable and create a new one and then everything works, but I would prefer a more effective way. Can I somehow remove one single item from the cached data?

**Edit**

My effective but ugly solution is following:

```
// whoever calls this function will have loaded all friends into
// the cache already, so a blocking get is fine
public void removeFriend(DBContact friend)
{
    if (mFriends == null)
        return;

    List<DBContact> data = RxManager.get()
            .getFriends()
            .toList()
            .blockingGet();

    data.remove(friend);

    mFriends = Observable
        .fromIterable(data)
        .compose(RxUtil.cacheAndShare());
}
```

Is that really the way to go?

Comment: Irreverent to the question but .cache().replay().refCount(); is somehow redundant.

Comment: As for the problem , I use a Subject/Relay instead of Observable and each time pass the newest value to each subscriber via onNext method. It still have some waste of resource but works fine for me.  Or if you can use fromCallable to get the newest data each time.

Comment: Why not simply use the appropriate operators e.g. `filter` instead of editing the underlying cached data?

Comment: @PhoenixWang what is redundant? the `replay` as the `cache` operator is enough? And I don't see a big advantage of using `Subjects`\ `Relays`, I still have to directly access the underlying data and change it....

Comment: @JohnWowUs because during the lifetime of my app there may be a lot of adds/removes and then the caching would lose it's effectiveness as those operations would all need to be executed over and over again... I want to have nearly instant access to already cached data

Comment: @prom85 yes cache is basically replay().autoConnect(). And for Subjects you can receive the new update for each subscriber. But if you want just every new subscribe receive the newest value. You can just use fromCallable.